# Oracle 11.2 Windows cannot startup with two lines

Tags: oracle

in the past I used to startup my Oracle 11.2 Windows with this little script:

```
NET START OracleServiceORCL
LSNRCTL START
```

Everything works fine. But now I found this failed:

```
C:\bin>LSNRCTL START

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 08-NOV-2017 11:02:52

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is C:\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to c:\alert\log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                08-NOV-2017 11:02:55
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 3 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I have to manually startup database like this:

```
C:\bin>sqlplus system/manager as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Nov 8 11:04:59 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 3407261696 bytes
Fixed Size                  2180504 bytes
Variable Size            2097154664 bytes
Database Buffers         1291845632 bytes
Redo Buffers               16080896 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

Can anybody tell me what may cause the script stops working please?

Comment: `sqlplus system/manager as sysdba` is to start the Oracle DB Client application. It doesn't start Oracle Database Server.

Comment: Does `startup` command works in all circumstances, if DB server on a same host or so in any other host. Someone might clarify over here, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to length of your `DB_NAME` and `ORACLE_SID`.

After you issue startup command, query for these :

```
select name from v$database;  -- gives you DB_NAME
select instance_name from v$instance;
```

> The length of `DB_NAME` is limited to **8** characters.
>
> `INSTANCE_NAME` defaults to `ORACLE_SID`. (From DOS prompt you may see
>   `ORACLE_SID` be issuing `echo %ORACLE_SID%` command, if set before)
>   Oracle document does not specify the limit for `INSTANCE_NAME` length.
>   However if you describe `V$INSTANCE` view you can see that column
>   `INSTANCE_NAME`  has `VARCHAR2(16)`, indicating the  limit of 16
>   characters.
>
> Because `INSTANCE_NAME` defaults to `ORACLE_SID` you need to be
>   careful when deciding `SID` before creating a database. **For a single
>   instance database** `ORACLE_SID`'s length should be **8**, also.  So
>   keep your `DB_NAME`, `INSTANCE_NAME` and `ORACLE_SID`'s lengths not
>   more than **8** characters, and i recommend you keep names three of
>   them are the same, and don't forget that the `ORACLE_SID` can contain
>   only the characters a-z, A-Z, and 0-9.

It seems `INSTANCE_NAME` & `DB_NAME` are **`CLRExtProc`** of length **10**, in your case. Re-install db with a name upto **8** characters.