# Why Oracle 11g XE listener stops working?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener, centos7

I have recently installed Oracle 11G XE on CentOS 7. For some reason the listener is stop working after it is initiated. I'm logging in to server with the user used to install the DB instance. To run the `lsnrctl` command I need to change to a user named `oracle` and load the environmental variables every time I change to this user, using the command `. ./dbenv.sh`.

This is the result when I execute `lsnrctl start`:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 08-NOV-2017 14:48:35

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora

Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml

Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.16.1.100)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                08-NOV-2017 14:48:37
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...

  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.16.1.100)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

When I execute the command `lsnrctl status` after a few seconds this is whats shown:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 08-NOV-2017 14:49:13

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.16.1.100)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

My listener.ora file contained this:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.16.1.100)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: your `instance_name` & `db_name` are `PLSExtProc` of length 10, for details please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170940/oracle-11-2-windows-cannot-startup-with-two-lines/47172036#47172036

Comment: look at /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/listener.log
What does it say?

Comment: Thank you both. The CentOS installation crashed, we decide to install the OS again, now we choose an Oracle Linux 6.9 distribution. The issue we have in this moment is that connections from Linux and Mac are ok, but Windows connections are rejected. Do you have some idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, we solved the Windows issue, the solution was to update the Oracle Driver, everything is working now.

Comment: Can you add more details to this answer?  Thanks.